# if $\int_{0}^{\infty}[f(t)-g(t)]dt\le 0$ then $\lim \limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}f(t)=0$? under below assumption

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, infinity

if the inequality $$\int_{0}^{\infty}[f(t)-g(t)]dt\le 0$$ holds
such that

$f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are (uniformly) continues functions, $0\le f(t)$, $0\le g(t)\lt k$ and
$\lim \limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}g(t)=0$, where $k$ is a positive constant.

then one can conclude that
$$\lim \limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}f(t)=0?$$

A proof or a counterexample .

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $k > 1$, and let $g(x) = \mathbf{1}_{(0, 1)}(x)$ smoothed out so that the total added area is $\epsilon$. Then let $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{(k, k+2^{-k})}(x)$$ smoothed out arbitrarily so that the total added area is $\epsilon$ (say, $\epsilon/2^k$ for the $k$th bump). We will have $$\int_0^{\infty} \left(f(x)-g(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = \left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k}\right]-1 = 0$$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: i think this function that u choose for $f(x)$ be non-continues in infinity.

Comment: barbalat lemma say that if $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)=1$ then $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=0$. your $f(x)$ violated the brabalat lemma.

Comment: barbalat lemma is wrong?

Comment: Barbalat's lemma requires $f$ to be uniformly continuous, not just continuous.

Comment: There's no such thing as "non-continuous at infinity" for functions defined on the real line. Consider $h(x) = \sin(x)$. This function is continuous everywhere, but $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \sin(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks a lot. if f(x) is a uniformly continuous function, so can i conclude $lim f(\infty)=0$ by this assumption?

Comment: If $g$ is integrable, then definitely. I'm thinking about what happens if $g$ is not integrable.

Comment: My question is exactly about $g$ is not integrabale. for example $g(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)}$. :)

Comment: Is the function $f$ uniformly continuous? that was part of the assumption

Comment: @guy-fsone yes, $f$ and $g$ are uniformly continues.

Comment: I would to know is that true

Comment: Yes I don't see how that is obvious

Comment: No, my $f$ is not uniformly continuous, but the question was edited to add the assumption. I might note that this is usually considered to be in poor taste after one has already received an answer for the question as asked.

Comment: @michael-lee $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ for $0<x<\infty$ is  uniformly continuous and we do not need the values of this function for other $x$s.